# Calling join in between a thread execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have 2 threads t1 and t2 which are executing parallelly. I have written something inside t1 and t2. 
After 3 lines of execution of t2, t1 should finish its execution and after that t2 should finish its execution. Can I achieve this with `Join()`?

I started coding something, but not sure how to do this.

```
public class JoinTest {

    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {



        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i =0; i< 10 ; i++) {
//                  System.out.println(i);
                    count++;
                }

            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i =0; i< 10 ; i++) {
//                  System.out.println(i);
                    count++;
                }

            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Comment: "*After 3 lines of execution of t2, t1 should finish its execution and after that t2 should finish its execution. Can I achieve this with `Join()?`*" - Why not try it out?

Comment: Do you mean to say, after three lines of execution, t2 should _wait_ for t1 to finish? If that's what you want, you can achieve it by having t2 call t1.join() at that point.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Exactly how I was trying to do. But how do I call t1.join in t2?

Comment: Just call it.  The `t1` variable should be in-scope within the body of the `t2` thread's `run()` method.  If you are using an older version of Java, then it may be necessary for you to make `t1` a `final` variable.

Comment: The Java language and Java standard libraries have no concept of  parent/child relationship or ownership between threads. All Java threads are peers. (Not thinking about thread _groups_ at this point, but then it looks like, neither were you.)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `t1.join()` inside t2's `run()` method, like so:

```
public class JoinTest {

    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {



        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i =0; i< 10 ; i++) {
//                  System.out.println(i);
                    count++;
                }

            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i =0; i< 10 ; i++) {
//                  System.out.println(i);
                    if (i == 2) {    //call t1.join() here, you can change this condition based on your logic
                       t1.join();
                    }
                    count++;                   
                }

            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
java multithreading
```

Comment: Can you see the output its giving. I tried this, did not give me the right output.

Comment: are you seeing a different output each time you run it or the same output? If it's the same output, then the join() is working and you just need to change the logic of when to call join().